# How to Authenticate/Authorize HotChocolate Graph API with FusionAuth API Key

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, fusionauth, hotchocolate, api-authorization

I am currently creating a Graph API in .net core with HotChocolate framework. I was able to implement custom JWT Bearer auth. However, our project requires FusionAuth to be used as auth provider and I am having trouble integrating it with the project.
Since, the project is a partner api, API key authentication is what we are looking to go with. Can anyone please provide an insight on how I can implement it? I am kind of new to these stuffs. Any help will be much appreciated.

I used, `HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Authorization` package for JWT auth. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for help with FusionAuth or .NET?

Comment: I figured out a workaround adding a custom authentication scheme which basically tries to fetch tenants from FusionAuth using the API key passed in request header. If there is a better solution, I would be happy to learn about it. And as I am new to FusionAuth, any help on it would mean a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the next releases and this will be changed = a lot of extended functionality. Current auth has some limitations.. Graphql itself do not provide auth stuff. But there will be new extension in HC for this... Just wait..